# Будет ли на JavaScript V8 4.9.385.35 работать стандарт ES2015? Браузер старый, но менять не советуйте. Вообще как соотносится версия JS с ES?

Tags: javascript, v8

Есть соответствующая таблица? Где почитать (не долго)?

Comment: См. также про историю версий и соотношение JS и ES: https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_history.html

Answer (score 2):

Откройте в вашем браузере [таблицу совместимости](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/). Первая колонка озаглавлена 'Current Browser', в ней приведена информация о том, какой функционал поддерживается в вашем браузере.